# Vowpal Wabbit Multiclass Linear Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, vowpalwabbit

Is it possible to train a multiclass (multinomial) **linear** classification model with Vowpal Wabbit Library?

I tried to use --oaa with --loss_function squared, but it seems that the default loss function for --oaa is logistic.

I am using [rcv1.multiclass](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html) as input.

One Solution:

I can create multiple version of the data as follows:

Version i: make all the labels zero except class I

Then I can train multiple binary classifications for each version of data. Finally, I can feed the test data to all the classifier and apply an argmax. Is there any better (automated) solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PurgeCSS and Tailwind CSS, how to preserve responsive classes using the Command Line Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554596/purgecss-and-tailwind-css-how-to-preserve-responsive-classes-using-the-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `vw --oaa N`, you will actually get a **linear** N-class classifier. To get a non-linear classifier you would need to add quadratic/polynomial features (`-q`, `--cubic`, `--interactions`) or kernels (`--ksvm`) or a hidden layer (`--nn`) or any other nonlinear reduction (`--lrq`, `--stage_poly`, `--autolink`).

The choice of loss function does not effect whether the classifier is linear or not. The default is `--loss_function=squared`. For classification, I would suggest to use `--loss_function=logistic` (possibly with `--probabilities` if you want to predict probability of each class) or `--loss_function=hinge` (if you care only about the top class).

> Then I can train multiple binary classifications for each version of data. Finally, I can feed the test data to all the classifier and apply an argmax. Is there any better (automated) solution?

Yes, this is exactly what `--oaa` does (but more efficiently).