# PurgeCSS and Tailwind CSS, how to preserve responsive classes using the Command Line Interface?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, tailwind-css, css-purge

I have the "full" 3.9 MB Tailwind CSS file and successfully applied PurgeCSS to reduce it to 9 kB. But it also purged all responsive classes like `md:px-6`, they don't show up in my purged version.

Note: this question is for using the command line interface (CLI)

This is what I did:

`purgecss --css ~/Desktop/Projects/Flask/Project1/build/static/css/main.css --content ~/Desktop/Projects/Flask//Project1/build/**/*.html --output ~/Desktop/Projects/Flask/Project2/static/css/main.css`

I chose to create the output file in a different folder (`Project2`) so that I could check on the input vs output.

One thing I tried is to add  `--safelist [/md/]`, but didn't help. In fact the safelist didn't seem to be used at all...

(I use CLI since it is part of a bigger Python Flask project)

Comment: I see I made a typo in the question itself, with a double slash in a file path, please ignore that. Question still holds

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PurgeCSS relies on [extractors](https://purgecss.com/extractors.html) to get the list of selectors used in a file. It provides a default extractor that is working fine with a wide variety of file types, but it can be limited and does not fit every CSS framework out there.

The default extractor considers every word of a file as a selector but it doesn't consider special characters like the colon (`:`) which is heavily used in Tailwind CSS.

So, by default, PurgeCSS removes responsive (`md:px-6`), hover (`hover:bg-gray-500`), etc. classes. To avoid this, Tailwind has its [own extractor](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/b19e291f6f329da8b1a61d4323bee6d04b99f31b/src/lib/purgeUnusedStyles.js#L25-L34). You could use this (or your very own) extractor but the PurgeCSS CLI has [limited options](https://purgecss.com/CLI.html#usage) and it's missing a `defaultExtractor` option.

Luckily, it accepts a config file option, so if you create your own `purgecss.config.js` file and add a default extractor in there, it will preserve these classes too. You can also add your other options to this file.

I used to use this simple extractor which will work for you too:

```js
(content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
```

Your config file will look like this:

```js
// purgecss.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ['build/**/*.html'],
  css: ['build/static/css/main.css'],
  defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
  output: 'static/css/main.css',
};
```

And you can use the following command to run PurgeCSS with the above config:

```bash
purgecss --config ./purgecss.config.js
```

*Edit:*

As [Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827129/fredrivett) mentioned in their comment, if you also want to include classes like `px-2.5`, you'll need to add a `.` to the character set:

```js
(content) => content.match(/[\w-/:.]+(?<!:)/g) || []
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Works like a charm.

I had to change the `output` folder in the `purgecss.config.js` file to make everything work in my specific flow, but that is a minor detail.

Comment: to also include classes such as `px-2.5` you'll want to match for `.` too, like so: `content.match(/[\w-:./]+(?<!:)/g) || []` (src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60552953/827129)

Comment: To use classes like `.max-w-[800px]`, the extractor should be updated to `(content) => content.match(/[\w\-:.\/\[#%\]]+(?<!:)/g) || []`

Answer (score 0):

Note: I want to comment on accepted answer, but my reputation is not enough for  comment.

I am working on a project written bootstrap and partially inject tailwind classes in it. Tailwind now not uses PurgeCSS, it compiles the classes Just In Time, and many fancy characters added to selectors. Normally you dont require use the PurgeCSS because tailwind only generates what you need, but if you are working on a legacy project and need purging but not purging generated tailwind classes the extractor must have all the fancy characters. I start with default Extractor and added every character in the group with prefixed a backslash like this: `\!`

- important `!`
- arbitrary values `[]`
- custom media queries `min-w-[400px]:`
- ampersand and greater than for immediate child selectors `[&>p]`
- percent values in arbitrary values `w-[19%]`
- rgb, or hsl arbitrary values requires parantheses `bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.5)]`
- arbitrary values sometimes requires "dot" in selector `.`
- asterisk for targeting every child selector `[&>*]`

Oh man, so many possibilities in arbitrary values!

Result is:

```js
defaultExtractor: (content) => {
  const defaultSelectors = content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/g) || [];
  const extendedSelectors = content.match(/[^<>"=\s]+/g) || [];
  return defaultSelectors.concat(extendedSelectors);
},
```

Edited: I write much simpler, blacklist approach regex.