# PurgeCSS misses Tailwind classes that use a colon:

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-purge

I have a website that uses tailwind. I'd like to keep the css size small, so I decided to use purgecss. I'm building the static site with python, so I'd like to use the CLI. Here's the code in my Makefile that handles this.

```
NODE_ENV=production npx purgecss --css css/*.css --content public/*.html public/**/*.html --output demo
npx uglifycss demo/*.css > public/style.css
rm -rf demo/*.css
```

Here's the thing though; it seems to make the css files smaller, but `purgecss` seems to completely skip any classes that have a colon (like `sm:grid-cols-2`). Take this html snippet:

```html
<ul class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 pt-4">
   ...
</ul>
```

Here's what the site looks like.

[image]

Here's what the site should look like.

[image]

The grid switches to `grid-cols-1` while the `lg:grid-cols-4` class should be triggered. Looking at the `public/style.css` I can also confirm that the `lg:grid-cols-4` class isn't listed.

Am I calling the `purgecss`-command wrong? It feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: Look for `.lg\:grid-cols-4` instead.

Comment: The `.lg\:grid-cols-4` class also does not exist.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [PurgeCSS and Tailwind CSS, how to preserve responsive classes using the Command Line Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554596/purgecss-and-tailwind-css-how-to-preserve-responsive-classes-using-the-command)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this is a duplicate question. The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554596/purgecss-and-tailwind-css-how-to-preserve-responsive-classes-using-the-command).